# Títulos das perguntas podem estar em inglês para referir-se a algo especificamente técnico?

Tags: debate

Editei o título de uma pergunta para algo mais adequado:

[Como resolver o erro "git clone problem with the ssl CA cert"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/172036/git-clone-problem-with-the-ssl-ca-cert)

No entanto, achei importante dar ênfase ao erro específico, o qual é orginalmente em inglês. Mantive em inglês porque normalmente o git exibe mensagens nesse idioma e ficaria estranho e difícil fazer consultas ao assunto futuramente caso seja traduzido para outro idioma, o português.

Nesses casos, é válido descrever o título em inglês?

Tentei algum jeito de enfiar algo em português mas ficaria muito longo.

Acredito que o importante é o contexto que obviamente está em português.

Comment: Sempre uso aspas para dar enfase que aquilo se trata da mensagem de erro, na verdade a maior parte das pergunta vejo algo como `Erro: "Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)"`, eu acho otimo titulos que já são o problema, se o erro for bem comum e evidente, ajuda muito as pessoas encontrarem a duvida e resposta desejada. Alguns exemplos http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=title%3aerro

Comment: Concordo, é coerente o que colocou. Postei aqui para ver se há objeções a cerca do assunto.  Então vou continuar como sempre fiz, que é semelhante ao que comentou.